# How to filter appProperty where null in Google Drive API?

Tags: php, google-api, google-drive-api, google-api-php-client

Am trying to filter files where property is null and where property has {key=1 and value=1} at the same time?

Here is my query string sent in the request:

```
'q'=>"'$FolderId' in parents 
    and (appProperties has null or appProperties has { key='1_id' and 
    value='1' })"
```